# Mysql SELECT if value exists, if not, calculate it and insert it

Tags: mysql

I am not sure if this can be done the way I want, I know I could easily manage to do this with PHP but due to some project specific limitations I can only use sql

Let's suppose I have a historic_sales table

```
------------------------
| year | month | total |
------------------------
| 1990 |    01 |     5 |
------------------------
| 1990 |    02 |    10 |
------------------------
| 1990 |    04 |    20 |
------------------------
```

I need to perform something LIKE this:

```
SELECT IF (total is NULL, 
  INSERT INTO historic_sales (year,month,total) 
  VALUES ('1990','03',
    SELECT SUM(totals) FROM orders WHERE year='1990' AND month = '03'), total) 
FROM historic_sales WHERE year = '1990' and month = '03'
```

What I want is first try to find needed total in historic_sales, If I can't find it, I'd then calculate it from the individual sales table and then save it to the historic_sales table.

Comment: You have any indexes at this table?

Comment: Why? Wouldn't it be simpler to create an outer join to a cartesian product of years and months? It would certainly be more efficient.

Comment: @symcbean can you explain more? maybe it is just that I was not clear enough, historic table have monthly totals that can be calculated from a sales table.

Comment: OK - just read this again - you're trying to create a batch updateable materialized view. You can't SELECT from the table at the same time you insert into it - but you can maintain a cached view of the table - a description of this is a bit invloved for a post here - see chapter 8 (from 8.5) in https://www.amazon.com/Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP-Performance-ebook/dp/B00U7E00H2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1483396901&sr=8-1&keywords=linux+apache+mysql+php+and+to+end

Comment: However an alternative approach would be to pre-consolidate using a trigger on order to add the value to the relevant row in historic_sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a function, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_total(yr VARCHAR(4), mth VARCHAR(2)) RETURNS double
BEGIN
DECLARE ttl DOUBLE;
SET ttl=(SELECT total FROM historic_sales WHERE year=yr AND month=mth);
IF ttl IS NULL THEN
    SET ttl=(SELECT SUM(totals) FROM orders WHERE year=yr AND month=mth);
    INSERT INTO historic_sales (year,month,total)
      VALUES (yr,mth,ttl);
END IF;
RETURN ttl;
END
```